# Building a hierarchy from flat array while promoting child nodes from unwanted node

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Have a function to create the hierarchy but need an efficient way to build it while removing unwanted nodes and promoting its children to a valid parent node.

http://jsfiddle.net/zx1scvbf

Note: Parent node will always appear before the child in the array.

```
Node { id: string, parentNodeId: string, flag: boolean, children: Node[] }; 


function buildTree(nodes) {
    var tree;
    var childrenOf = new Map();
    nodes.forEach(node => {
        if (!childrenOf.has(node.id)) {
            childrenOf.set(node.id, []);
        }
        node.childNodes = childrenOf.get(node.id);
        if (node.parentId != null) {
            childrenOf.has(node.parentId) ?
                childrenOf.get(node.parentId).push(node) : childrenOf.set(node.parentId, [node]);
        } else {
            tree = node;
        }
    });
    return tree;
}
```

Remove nodes when the flag is true, in the jsfiddle json, need to remove node.id 1 and 2 while promoting 3 as a child node to node 0. Above function will not remove when the flag is true, it just builds the hierarchy.

Expected Output for the example in the fiddle:

```
   {  
   "id":"0",
   "parentId":null,
   "children":null,
   "flag":"false",
   "childNodes":[  
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "parentId":"2",
         "children":null,
         "flag":"false",
         "childNodes":[  
            {  
               "id":"4",
               "parentId":"3",
               "children":null,
               "flag":"false",
               "childNodes":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "id":"5",
               "parentId":"3",
               "children":null,
               "flag":"false",
               "childNodes":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"6",
         "parentId":"0",
         "children":null,
         "flag":"false",
         "childNodes":[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. Tell us what undesirable results you're getting. Also, define "efficient".

Comment: Undesirable result: Nodes present even when flag is true. Efficient: O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Here's javascript approach based on recursion call (unlimited depth of "parenting"), it could be easily applied to the typescript project:

```
const buildTreeHierarchy = (nodes, perentId) => {
    const result = nodes
      .filter(n => n.parentId === perentId && n.flag !== 'true')
      .map(n => ({...n, children: buildTreeHierarchy(nodes, n.id)}));
    return result.length ? result : null;
}

buildTreeHierarchy(example, null);
```

The `example` argument is your initial JSON array.

Comment: WIthout recursion?

Comment: Are you afraid of recursion? ;) How many levels may have your data?

Comment: Not afraid, but looking for elegant iterative solution and no doubt it is nice recursive one.

Comment: If you have more than 2 levels, non-recursion solution would not be elegant anyway.

Comment: It will be more than 2 levels but other thing to note is that parent will always appear before the child in the array.

Comment: Okey, maybe someone could do it for you, but here I'm sure that for js/ts (as for functional language) the recursion is more then appropriate.

Comment: Node 3 linked to Node 2 (not 0). Then Node 2 is removed due to "flag":"true".